# How to delete this kind of file using a reserved name?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, passwords

Hi for everyone in stackoverflow !

I'm looking for a workaround to how delete this kind of file using a reserved name such :

`(nul, aux, com1, prn, etc...)`

So, i get as output error :

> The syntax of the file name, directory or volume incorrect.

```
@echo off
echo hello world>\\?\"%temp%\nul:nul"
pause
more<"%temp%\nul:nul"
pause
set /p MyVar=<"\\?\%temp%\nul:nul"
echo %MyVar%
Pause
Del "\\?\%temp%\nul:nul" /F
pause
```

I'm using this trick to store the password shown like in this code below
so, i can set the password into this file and also, read from it, but i can't delete it.

```
@echo off
Title %~n0 with colors by Hackoo
Mode 50,5 & Color 0E
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:CreatePassword
Call :InputPassword "Please choose your password" pass1
Call :InputPassword "Please confirm your password" pass2
If !pass1!==!pass2! ( Goto:Good ) Else ( Goto:Bad )
::***********************************
:InputPassword
Cls
echo.
echo.
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host '%1' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set %2=%%p
Goto :eof
::***********************************       
:Good
Cls
echo.
echo.
Call :Color 0B "                  Good password  " 1  
TimeOut /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
Call :Write_Info
Call :Collect_Info
echo Your password stored as : "!SavedPass!" without quotes
pause
Goto :Eof
::***********************************
:Bad
Cls
echo.
echo.
Call :Color 0C "            Wrong password try again " 1                
TimeOut /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
Goto :CreatePassword
::***********************************
:Color
for /F "delims=." %%a in ('"prompt $H. & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
set nL=%3
if not defined nL echo Requires third argument & Pause > nul & goto :Eof
if %3 == 0 (
    <nul set /p ".=%BS%">%2 & Findstr /V /A:%1 /R "^$" %2 nul & Del %2 2>&1
    goto :Eof
) else if %3 == 1 (
    echo %BS%>%2 & Findstr /V /A:%1 /R "^$" %2 nul & Del %2 2>&1
    goto :Eof
)
::***********************************
:Write_Info
(echo !Pass2!)>\\?\"%temp%\nul:nul"
Call :Color 0A "          Your password is set sucessfuly" 1 
::***********************************   
:Collect_Info
(set /P SavedPass=)<"\\?\%temp%\nul:nul"
goto :eof
::***********************************
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
del "\\.\%temp%\nul"
```

As Microsoft says in
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/120716,
you need to use a syntax which bypasses the check for reserved names.